# How can I edit the default order of sql table ( when you edit manually )?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

How can I edit the default order of sql table ( when you edit manually )?
I have seen someone asks this question, but he has no answers.
I'm talking about the case you pressing “edit top 'N' rows” or ”Edit all rows” in my case.
Example: Here is the default order of the table 'comments':

```
ID | value 
---+-------
1  | Cool 
2  | Amazing 
3  | Great 
5  | Ok
4  | Wonderful
```

I want to change the order to the query "`select * from comments order by ID`",
then, by pressing on "Edit All Rows" The default order by will be:

```
ID | value 
---+-------
1  | Cool 
2  | Amazing 
3  | Great 
4  | Wonderful 
5  | Ok
```

Comment: There is no default order in SQL. Unless you specify the `Order by` order of result set is not guaranteed

Answer (score 1):

### Use a View

Create a view using the ordered query as follows: `CREATE VIEW ordered_comments as select * from comments order by ID`

Then right click your `ordered_comments` view and choose edit top N rows.

Answer (score 1):

1. Right Click On Table and Edit Top 200 Rows
2. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd>
3. Click the Sort Order For Row ID and select 1
4. Click the Sort Type for Row ID and select Ascending

Comment: It doesn't change the default view, I could also do CTRL + 3 and to add my order query.. Thank you but it's not what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server use this way:

1. Store your data in a temp-table:

   ```
   SELECT * 
   INTO #tempTable
   FROM yourTable;
   ```
2. Delete current data from your table:

   ```
   DELETE FROM yourTable;
   ```
3. Restore your data from temp-table:

   ```
   INSERT INTO yourTable
   SELECT * 
   FROM #tempTable
   ORDER BY fieldsToOrder;
   ```

Comment: It's not working, it doesn't restore the data with the order affect, it restores it exactly how it was :(

Answer (score -1):

you can create a column called row_index, and set numbers for each row and select rows ordered by your row_index.

```
select * from table1 order by row_index
```